# How to make sense of dependent count data in a generalized linear model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, count-data, medicine

I am investigating whether fitting my data to a generalised linear model is a) possible and b) worth it.

My data set is a list of retrospective-longitudinal patient medical records. I am able to identify an interval of time before each patient takes a particular drug. In this interval of time, I count the number of headache medical indications and I record the interval duration in days. Note: the interval of time is not fixed across the population, it is based on when a patient falls into a period of chronic headache.

What I am left with is a list of headache intervention counts **HeadacheCount**, the size of the interval in days, **IntervalSize** and the particular drug name in question **DrugName**. There will be multiple drugs to test for. e.g.,

```
**DrugName  IntervalSize  HeadacheCount**
A            96           10
A            123          11
A            134          15
A            101          9
B            546          88
B            707          65
C            15           1
C            45           4
C            29           1
....
```

I am expecting to find that patients who go on very strong headache/migraine therapeutics, will either have more headache indications before the drug event and/or have a longer preheadache interval; I suspect they are both the same but measured one as event counts and the other as interval duration.

I am unsure how to fit this to a generalised linear model in R. I suspect the headache indication counts are not random variables, i.e., they are not independent as chronic headaches are tightly dependent on the one before. What distribution should I use and how would I formulate the right-hand side i.e.,  glm(IntervalSize ~ DrugName ????)

Comment: Do you have information about the patients? If so, they could be the random effect.

Comment: What information are you interested in?

Comment: Additional column that identifies patients, that is for each row a patient id?

Comment: Hi, yes I have all of that information. How does that mitigate that for this particular count data, the events (counts) are not going to be independent? I've seen examples of Poisson and quasipoisson distributions in GLM, but both distributions assume the count data are random variables, i.e. , independent from one another.

Comment: That's what the random effect is for. By including the patient in the model as a random effect you are taking into effect that each patients measurement is dependent.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm in the deep end with these particular models. I'll give it a try.